# iterate digits in a number as long as its the same number

Tags: javascript

I need to loop through digits of a number , until there is a difference in thats number , and then output the number length :

For example :

> 0000123

so the output should be 3.

(eliminate `0000` and output `123`)

How can I tackle it ?

Comment: need only to remove zero or any number ie 1111234 to 234 ?

Comment: not only zero , but any number in a sequence..

Comment: what do you want if the input is `11112341`? Would it be `2341` or `234`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try looping on string until you find difference:

```js
var num="001234",i,max=num.length,output;
for(i=1;i<max;i+=1){
 if(num[i]!== num[i-1]){
      output = num.substring(i,max);
      break;
 }   
}

alert(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use ES5 features like [*filter*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.20):

```
var n = '11112213133';
var test = true;

console.log(String(n).split('').filter(function(v,i,a) {
  test = test? v == a[0] : test;
  return !test;
}).join(''));   // 2213133
```

You can also use simple string methods (which are probably hugely faster):

```
var n = '11112213133';

var i = 0, c = n.charAt(0);
while (c == n.charAt(++i)) {}
console.log(n.substr(i));   // 2213133
```

Though these will trim the first number whether it's repeated or not.